# Perl one liner to add text at last but one line of a large file

Tags: perl

I am novice to Perl. Please help me in the programming using either one liner or a Perl proc or a Perl program.
Let's suppose my input file is input.txt and its contents are as follows :

```
This is an example 

This file has three lines

Oh you are mistaken. It has many lines 

I want my text here 

Thanks for making it to the last line of input.txt.
```

Below is the output file that I want to generate:

```
This is an example 

This file has three lines

Oh you are mistaken. It has many lines 

I want my text here

This line has special characters like $

I love this community 

Thanks for making it to the last line of input.txt
```

I am running this on tcsh. I used the below one-liner :

```
Perl -p -e 'print "This line has special characters like $ \nI love this community"' if $. == 9' input.txt > output.txt
```

The problem is that, in the above example, I know the number of last line. But in my code, the length of input.txt keeps changing. What changes should I make to the one-liner so that it works even if I don't give the last line number.

Note: please don't suggest using sed. I tried with sed and I was successful at performing the required task. However, my input file is around 325MB and sed is taking neraly 25 mins to do this task. I want it to be done in less than 5 mins.

Perl version being used : v5.10.1

Comment: What is the sed approach that's taking *25 minutes*? That seems excessive even on hardware from the 90's.

Comment: Hi Shawn, the sed approach was a little different. I matched a pattern and inserted text before the pattern. It was like the following: sed -i -e '/^Thanks/i This line has special characters I love this community' input.txt        I used to take a backup of input.txt and then perform this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of fixed line number, check whether it is end of input file with [`eof`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof)

```
perl -pe 'print "This line has special characters like \$ \nI love this community\n" if eof' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. You saved me from opening 150 files and inserting text. The Perl script is taking less than 30 sec.  Huge respect !

Comment: Can't upvote it as i require atleast 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed` to insert text before the last line of input:

```sh
 sed '$i This line has special characters like $\nI love this community' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This should be orders of magnitude faster than your version using a regular expression to decide when to insert.

Comment: Damn! This one takes less than 10 sec to execute.